# Edges enter tangentially and not perpendicular to the node

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

In the following code, treat the circles as nodes. The edges should be directed to the center of the node, not meet it tangentially as is evident in the white vertex. I don't know which order I missed, or what the cause is. Could you spot it?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{automata}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3,  
    semithick,auto,
      every state/.style={inner sep=.54mm,text=black,minimum size=0}]


\begin{scope}

    \foreach \i     in {0}
    {
    \node[state,minimum size=0,circle, draw,fill=red] (A\i) at (45*\i:2) {}; }
    \foreach \j     in {1}
    {\node[state,minimum size=0,circle, draw,fill=white] (A\j) at (45*\j:2) {}; 
    }


    \foreach \k  in {0}{
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\jp}{\k +1} 
   \path[-] 
    (A\k) edge[bend left=30] (A\jp)
    (A\k) edge[bend left=-30] (A\jp)
    (A\k) edge  (A\jp)
    ;
    }   
    \end{scope}    
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: In your MWE, `\jp` is a float value (`1.0`). Try `\pgfmathsetmacro{\jp}{int(\k +1)}` to get integer value (`1`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can instead `\pgfmathsetmacro{\jp}{int(\k +1)}`, as suggested *Paul Gaborit* in his comment, use new counter:

```
\foreach \k [count=\jp from 1] {...}
```

Complete MWE, with some small changes to yours is:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3,
    semithick, auto,
    bend angle=30,
    every state/.style={inner sep=.54mm, text=black, minimum size=0}]
    \foreach \i     in {0}
    {
    \node[state,minimum size=0,circle, draw,fill=red] (A\i) at (45*\i:2) {}; }
    \foreach \j     in {1}
    {\node[state,minimum size=0,circle, draw,fill=white] (A\j) at (45*\j:2) {};
    }
    \foreach \k [count=\jp from 1] in {0}{
   \path    (A\k) edge[bend left] (A\jp)
            (A\k) edge[bend right] (A\jp)
            (A\k) edge  (A\jp);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]